# Field recorder help

Tags: field-recording, newbie

I am looking for a good quality sounding field recorder that is not to expensive. I am in between the zoom H2n
, sony pcm- m10, sony pcm-d50, or fostex f2-2le. I will also be getting a rode nt4 and rycote wind shield kit #4
Last thing, is the rode sm3 shockmount the right one to use in a zepplin with a rode nt4?

Comment: Please spend some time searching this site as there are many threads dedicated to this very question.

Comment: As Jay said, spend some time searching, there are a bunch of threads on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By H2n you mean the H4n, right? If so, then The H4n is pretty good for the money but a bit short on Battery power, especially if you are using phantom.

I have used both the H4n and the Fostex and my preference is more for the Fostex. I never really use onboard microphones, like the H4n, unless it is sheer gorilla recordings I need. If you are looking for more professional layout and preformance, I would use the Fostex.

I have also used in the past an older version of the Marantz PMD661 which I liked quite a bit. The battery life was a lot longer as it holds 4AAs.

In short: Fostex is my choice.

can't comment on the Sony ones

Answer (score 1):

The Rode SM3 will fit with the NT4 but I'm not sure how the sm3 will fit to the zepplin. Have you seen the [Rode Blimp](http://rodemic.com/accessory.php?product=Blimp) this is designed for the NT4 and NTG series.
BTW the NT4 is a great mic - mine goes with me almost everywhere :)